# Passing props in a component that is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a simple and straight up question.

So we can store react components in a variable. But now, I want to know if it is possible pass props to a component if it is stored in a variable?

```js
//////////////////////////////////////////////
//////  Normal & typical React component
//////////////////////////////////////////////

const myComponent = <Hello name={'Jamie'} /> 

render () {

  return myComponent;

}


////////////////////////////////////////
//////  What I want
////////////////////////////////////////

const myComponent = <HelloWorld /> 

// I want to be able to add that props here
// something like myComponent.addProps({'name': 'jamie'});

render () {

  return myComponent;

}
```

My problem is well beyond just this. I wanted to know if we have such a feature in React API.

Comment: But why are you storing the component in a variable at all? React already does all the smart diffing for you based on what `render()` returns, so just use `render() { return <Hello ...>; }` and let React do its job.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans as I mentioned the problem is not just diffing and etc. I have around hundreds of components and I want to apply, filter and map these components with different logic and I want to add props completely dynamic.

Comment: Yeah: do that in render. Generate all your components as part of your render call, and if you have hundreds of components: organise them. React is a UI library, and your UI is always reducible to "things that control a handful of other things", not hundreds of things. Use state/props for the data that you're going to generat components off of, and then build those components in render(), and let React decide whether that means it _actually_ rebuilds them or not. That's what it's designed for. Use the `key` property the way it's meant to and React does the rest.

Comment: I believe you are more concerned about other stuff rather than the question. There was a reason that I eliminated other stuff and just asked this question. I just want to know if in React ecosystem and API we have such a feature.

Comment: The problem with that is that you reduced your example to the point where it doesn't make sense: if what you're asking about is related to what you're showing, what you're showing is bad practice and don't do that. So please edit your question to something for which your question makes sense? The only true answer to your question paired with your code is "don't do this."

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans  If it doesn't make sense to you doesn't mean it's not understandable. Ashraful Islam just said one thing and that was answer.  Is that simple question not really understandable to you?

Comment: just because someone else gets it doesn't mean it's suddenly a well-asked question. Remember that your question is not just for you, it's also for every other future visitor who has a similar problem and is looking for an answer. If your question was just "if I already have a component, how do I update its props" then you don't need any of the additional explanation and code: just ask that, without any code that shows a single var, and that var only getting used in render().

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Remember you were paying attention to a lot of other details, such as diffing algorithm in React and ....   By including those in question it would be more confusing....   I said and I mentioned I am targeting React API but you still were concerned about how I structure my code ......

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can try like following,

```
React.cloneElement(
  myComponent,
  {prop1: "prop value"}
)
```

Reference Doc: [React Official Doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Asraful, this helped me a lot. Just used it and fixed my problem. Maybe I it is not efficient but what you showed is what I needed. 

Comment: As the answer from react official doc. I don't think about efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

Went through kind of same issue in typeScript, had a list of menuItem to map on it in JSX, each one containing a different React Component for icon like this:

```
const menuItems: {label: string, icon: React.FC, selected:boolean}[] = [
{label: 'Home', icon: <HomeIcon/>, selected: false}, 
{label: 'Live TV', icon: <ScreenIcon/>, selected: false}, 
{label: 'VOD', icon: <PlayIcon/>, selected: true},
{label: 'Podcasts', icon: <MicIcon/>, selected: false},
{label: 'Games', icon: <GameIcon/>, selected: false},
{label: 'App', icon: <MenuIcon/>, selected: false},
{label: 'Services', icon: <ShopIcon/>, selected: false},
{label: 'Languages', icon: <WorldIcon/>, selected: false},];
```

But I needed to give a "fill" props to the icon if the menuItem was selected or focused, so I changed my array like this:

```
const menuItems: {label: string, icon: React.FC, selected:boolean}[] = [
{label: 'Home', icon: HomeIcon, selected: false}, 
{label: 'Live TV', icon: ScreenIcon, selected: false}, 
{label: 'VOD', icon: PlayIcon, selected: true},
{label: 'Podcasts', icon: MicIcon, selected: false},
{label: 'Games', icon: GameIcon, selected: false},
{label: 'App', icon: MenuIcon, selected: false},
{label: 'Services', icon: ShopIcon, selected: false},
{label: 'Languages', icon: WorldIcon, selected: false},];
```

And Called it like this:

```
    const FocusableListItem: FC<ExportableProps> = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles(props);

  return (
    <ListItem button key={props.label} className={classes.button} >
      <ListItemIcon>
        <props.icon fill={props.focused || props.selected ? '#6648ff' : '#c4c4c4'}></props.icon>
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText>{props.label}</ListItemText>
    </ListItem>
  );
};
```

With this kind of interface for props:

```
interface ExportableProps extends withFocusableProps {
  label: string;
  icon: React.FC<{fill: string}>;
  onClick?: () => void;
  disabled?: boolean;
  selected?: boolean;
  small?: boolean;
}
```

And works perfectly ! Don't know if it'll help someone but looks useful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Capitalize your variable name and use normal Jsx syntax:

```js
const MyComponent = <HelloWorld /> 

render () {
  return <MyComponent name='jamie'/>
}
```

This is allows things like storing components in an array:

```js
import {
  EmailShareButton,
  FacebookShareButton,
  InstapaperShareButton,
  LineShareButton,
  LinkedinShareButton,
  LivejournalShareButton,
  MailruShareButton,
  OKShareButton,
  PinterestShareButton,
  PocketShareButton,
  RedditShareButton,
  TelegramShareButton,
  TumblrShareButton,
  TwitterShareButton,
  ViberShareButton,
  VKShareButton,
  WhatsappShareButton,
  WorkplaceShareButton,
} from "react-share"

export default class LikeShare extends Component {
  shareButtons = [
    EmailShareButton,
    FacebookShareButton,
    InstapaperShareButton,
    LineShareButton,
    LinkedinShareButton,
    LivejournalShareButton,
    MailruShareButton,
    OKShareButton,
    PinterestShareButton,
    PocketShareButton,
    RedditShareButton,
    TelegramShareButton,
    TumblrShareButton,
    TwitterShareButton,
    ViberShareButton,
    VKShareButton,
    WhatsappShareButton,
    WorkplaceShareButton,
  ]

  render = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.shareButtons.map(
          ShareButton => <ShareButton url={window.location.href}/>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: This method is right, but you take a mistake. Original component assign as a pure value, not JSX. It must be: ```const MyComponent = HelloWorld;```

Answer (score -2):

you can use setProps also like

```
myComponent.setProps({name: 'jamie'});
```